# Strange discrepancy between library reference and compiler for std::upper_bound()

Tags: c++, stl, std

I need to process a list of objects of type `Foo` in groups sharing the quality of corresponding to the same value of `Bar`. The list is pre-sorted in relation to that quality,  so my idea was to use `std::upper_bound` to find where the subsequent groups begin.

```
Bar FooToBar(const Foo &foo);
// sorted so that FooToBar(foolist[0] <= FooToBar(foolist[1]) <= ...
std::list<Foo> foolist; 

// find bounds of a group of Foo-s corresponding to someBar;
Bar someBar;
auto 
    groupBegin = foolist.begin(),
    // find last item of foolist whose FooToBar() == someBar
    groupEnd   = std::upper_bound( foolist.begin(), 
                                   foolist.end(), 
                                   someBar );
```

Of course that will not work because `Foo` and `Bar` are not directly comparable. Luckily, there's an overload of `std::upper_bound` which takes an extra comparator argument:

```
groupEnd = std::upper_bound( foolist.begin(), foolist.end(), someBar, Compare);
```

Question is, how do I go about writing `Compare()`? Here's where things get interesting. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) says:

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
>
> The signature does not need to have const &, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.
>   The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type T can be implicitly converted to both Type1 and Type2, and an object of type ForwardIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both Type1 and Type2. ​

Obviously, there's no way I can satisfy those conditions with `Foo` and `Bar`. However, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/?kw=upper_bound) says something different:

> Binary function that accepts two arguments (the first is always val, and the second of the type pointed by ForwardIterator), and returns a value convertible to bool.

I can work with that, so:

```
bool Compare(const Bar &bar, const Foo &foo) { /* ... */ }
```

However, that does not compile in either VS2013, nor g++:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:141:37: error: cannot convert ‘Foo’ to ‘Bar’ in argument passing

Curiously, when I reverse the argument order, it compiles, runs and behaves as expected:

```
bool Compare(const Foo &foo, const Bar &bar) { /* ... */ }
```

So it looks like one reference says one thing, other reference says something else, and the compiler accepts something still different. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Note that the order or argument type for Compare is different between `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

Comment: Yes, cppreference's `Compare` template is broken. Many algorithms *do* require the comparator to be callable both ways, but not `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

Comment: @T.C. perhaps it should just be reduced to a link to Compare concept, which is more precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're refering to is a defect in the standard: [#270](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#270). The original wording was deemed to strict (indeed, your particular use case was mentioned). The section in the Standard now reads, [upper.bound]:

> ```
> template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
>   ForwardIterator
>     upper_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
>                 const T& value);
>
> template<class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
>   ForwardIterator
>     upper_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
>                 const T& value, Compare comp);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: The elements `e` of `[first,last)` shall be partitioned with respect to the expression `!(value < e)` or `!comp(value, e)`.
>   *Returns*: The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first,last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first,i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `!(value < *j)` or `comp(value, *j) == false`.

In both cases, `value` is the first argument to `comp` and the element is second. So the following is perfectly valid code:

```
struct Foo { };
struct Bar { };

std::vector<Foo> foolist;

auto it = std::upper_bound(foolist.begin(), foolist.end(), Bar{}, 
                           [](Bar const&, Foo const&) { return false; });
```

The above works on both gcc 5.2 (and even 4.6.4 -- modulo the lambda -- which is the oldest I have easy access to) and clang 3.6.

Comment: That leaves only the fact that I had to use a reverse the argument order to get it to compile, in need of an answer. Unfortunately, I don't have this code handy at the moment and I cannot reproduce it any more. Probably a stupid mistake on my part, but I'll be sure to investigate and report.

Comment: @neuviemeporte That's a compiler error. The `Bar` should be the first argument for `upper_bound` (but the second argument for `lower_bound`).

Comment: You're probably right, I was investigating both and I must have mixed them up at some point. Accepting then. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the part of the documentation that you quoted in your question, you will understand that unless there is an implicit conversion from `Bar` to `Foo`, both versions of `Compare` are incorrect. The fact that one version works is merely a lucky coincidence. It may easily fail with a different compiler.

Comment: Are you sure? The link provided by @Barry shows how the standard was purposefully altered to allow cases in which no direct conversion exists. And I don't see how I might have been just lucky, the types in my original code were completely unrelated (a list of raw pointers vs. an unrelated struct).

Comment: @neuviemeporte, based on the documentation you quoted, I am sure. When the standard fixes the documentation and the vendors implement the new behavior, the first version your function should work while the second version should not.

Comment: OK, so how do we tell whether it's the standard that's ahead or the docs that are behind, and at which point in time it becomes safe to use the new version in code that's meant to be portable?

Comment: If you are able to compare a `Bar` with a `Foo`, there must be something common between the two types. Can you create a temporary `Foo` from `someBar` and use the temporary `Foo`?

Comment: No, I cannot. But looking at the implementation of `lower_bound()` in VC++ headers, there's nothing that would require that conversion to work - it just calls the predicate with `!_Pred(_Val, *_Mid)`. Which confirms what @Barry is saying - his `Foo` and `Bar` are also as unrelated as possible.

Comment: Strange. Why does your first version fail, then?